# NodeJS server hangs and not timing out, no response returned thereafter

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, keystonejs

My `NodeJS` server has been freezing out and not returning any kinds of error.

See logs attached for more info.

Recently made a huge switch to async/await pattern which I believe could be the cause of this issue. Have written all async/awaits like this:

```
// PostController.js
view.on('init', async (next) => {
    try {
        const promises = [
            Post.model.fetchDetail(req.params.post),
            Treatment.model.fetchTreatmentCategories(),
            User.model.fetchMostViewedDoctors(),
        ];

        const [
            post,
            categories,
            doctors,
        ] = await Promise.all(promises);

        locals.data.post = post;
        locals.data.categories = categories;
        locals.data.doctors = doctors;

        if (post && post.tags) {
            locals.data.relatedQuestions = await Question.model.fetchRelatedQuestions(post.tags);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    next();
});
```

Have also placed the unhandledRejection event listener in my app's `init` file

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
    console.log('unhandledRejection', error, error.message);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are some methods to handle asynchronous in JavaScript:

1. Callbacks
2. Promises
3. Generators
4. Async/Await (ES7 feature)

Inside your code you are using `async/await` feature within a `callback`. Therefore you're **mixing up** method 1 and method 4 on the above list. I don't think it is the best idea. For a brief comparison take a look at [this link](https://hackernoon.com/from-callbacks-to-async-await-25331b7f73).